# Oracle: New database vs new user.schema?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, schema

Backstory: I had this database dropped in my lap when the company, I began working for last October, won the contract.  The developers gave me very little turn over, so I am digging back in my memory to when I maintained an Oracle DB in 2002.  My skills are extremely dated, so please be gentle.

Oracle 10.2.0.0.0   Windows Server 2003

My customer now wants me to create a blank copy of an existing application/database for a future effort.  My 1st idea was to clone the existing database and remove all the data.  However, I seem to remember working on a project years ago that led me to believe I could clone the existing user/schema and not have the whole other database to maintain.  There is a high possibility this new application will never be used, and I'd like to do the least amount of work as possible.   The current database is small.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the database have enough space for a copy of the schema(s), or the server enough free space that could be added? Would a new DB go on a new server, or would you be expected to share? Does the application rely on anything that would making sharing a database difficult, like hard-coded schema names in object references, or public synonyms?

Comment: More than enough space.  This database and associated app would be for future use.  It would eventually replace the current app/database as the default and the current one would be come legacy.  There is minimal hard coding.  I just hate to set up the whole new database and they decide that they don't need it any more.  Not lazy, just trying to make the best use of my time.

Comment: A new schema sounds like the way to go then. I'm not sure what you're looking for; advice on which is better, or how to actually do the clone (either way, as a new schema or the same schema in a new DB), or both?

Comment: Advice on what would you do in my situation.

Comment: After doing more research, it has dawned on me that in the rare event that the new application is funded and takes off, just creating another user would quickly become a pain.  I want to create another database instance on the existing server (there is enough room).  Is there anything I need to pay attention to that I am forgetting?   Thanx.

Comment: Also, this site is a breath of fresh air.  I haven't worked much with creating stuff in 10 years or so.  Most of what I did was via Enterprise Manager, SQL Developer, or backup/recovery stuff that had already been set up; basically a glorified operator.  I used to get my info from the Oracle Technical Network.  However, recent questions were answered with less than kindness.  I'm old and the outpouring of help is greatly appreciated.   Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

You can export the database with the `rows=n` parameter:

```
exp username/password@db owner=abc rows=n
```

This will export everything except the data.

Then if you want to import it, you can change users if needed:

```
imp username/password@db fromuser=abc touser=xyz
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use datapump(expdp/impdp) from 10g onwards. You can go through following commands:

--Export dump in source server:

```
expdp user/password directory=oracle_directory dumpfile=mydump_abc.dmp logfile=mydump_abc_export.log schemas=abc content=metadata_only
```

--Import dump in destination server

```
impdp user/password directory=oracle_directory1 dumpfile=mydump_abc.dmp logfile=mydump_abc_restore.log remap_schema=abc:xyz
```